# qdir.h conflicts with x.h (X11): how to resolve?

Tags: c++, qt, x11

I'm trying to use QFileDialog in a project which uses QDir. Simply including the the file results in compilation errors (Qt version is 4.8.5):

```
In file included from file.qt.cpp:25:
In file included from another_file.qt.h:26:
In file included from /usr/include/QtCore/QDir:1:
/usr/include/QtCore/qdir.h:107:21: error: expected '}'
               Unsorted    = 0x03,
               ^
/usr/include/X11/X.h:540:19: note: expanded from macro 'Unsorted'
#define Unsorted                0
                                ^
/usr/include/QtCore/qdir.h:104:19: note: to match this '{'
    enum SortFlag { Name        = 0x00,
                  ^
[... some more errors, but I think these are related to the above error ...]


6 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Volume2.dir/OGLFrame.qt.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Volume2.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've checked qdir.h and there is a closing bracket. But as the error suggests there is a conflict between the #define in X.h and the enum element. I've found a bug report from 8 years ago (http://code.mythtv.org/trac/ticket/1417) that suggests to include Qt headers before X11 headers. Since I'm not including X.h myself but rather linking against X11 I'm pretty sure it's not applicable here.

That leaves the question how to resolve this conflict? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible change the order of includes, or do a #undef Unsorted before including qdir.h to clean up the mess of x.h

Comment: Yep. Always include X headers *last*.